# goto #top of page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get jquery to move to the top of the page each time someone clicks a nav button.

When some clicks a button it hides the old content and shows the new, but it doesn't reset the browser scroll position, and thus the end user will get a bit confused.

So I thought to add in some `window.location.hash` JS commands to fix this, but this only works the first time it's executed.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#prac-btn").click(function() {
        $('#myTab a[href="#prac-page"]').tab('show');
        window.location.hash = "#top";
    });
    $("#act-btn").click(function() {
        $('#myTab a[href="#act-page"]').tab('show');
        window.location.hash = "#top";
    });
    $("#pro-btn").click(function() {
        $('#myTab a[href="#pro-page"]').tab('show');
        window.location.hash = "#top";
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Try with just a link with an empty href `#`

Comment: It does not work because it already is #top. You should clear it and re set it. But it is a much better practice to just use .scrollTo, as duskwuff mentioned.

Comment: I tried the clear option just after posting this and yes it does work, but as you said, it's better practice to use .scollTo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the scroll position, just do so directly:

```
window.scrollTo(0);
```

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I needed. I done a google to move to the top or scroll to the top, but none of the top results I checked had this.

Answer (score 0):

You want scrollTop:

```
$(window).animate({scrollTop:0});
```

This is the JQuery way to do it.